# OpenAPI springboot generator does not set default value for nullable fields in models

Tags: swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

When I create models using openAPI generator for springboot, the default value for nullable fields is not being set in models. Is there a way to get it generated with the default value present ?

```
  MyModel:
      type: object
      properties:
        data1:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          default: 10
          nullable: true
```

This generates a java class as -

```
public class MyModel   {
  @JsonProperty("data1")
  private JsonNullable<Integer> data1 = JsonNullable.undefined();
```

I would expect it to create it as **JsonNullable.of(10)** instead so that the default value is used.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. Did you figure something out?
It feels useless to define it then, if it is just defaulted to null.

Comment: Not yet. I read somewhere that default value is logically applicable only if nullable is false. I'm not very sure on that.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, did you end up finding a solution? The default values do not get generated as @Schema annotation properties in the generated classes, and subsequently in the generated spec with springdoc.